# Download attachments from latest email with subject containing specific text

Tags: vba, outlook

I have code that downloads the attachment (xlsb) from the last email in my inbox.

I have two problems:

1 - I need to change this so it looks for the first email (latest) first.

2 - It should only look for emails with a subject containing the words: DOCUMENT_APP (the name varies but it always has document_app in it, so it needs to use a wildcard)

This is the code I have which looks for the oldest email and saves the xlsb attachment file (disregarding the subject):

```vb
Sub DownloadAttachmentFirstEmail()

    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.StatusBar = "Downloading email"
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim oOlAp As Object, oOlns As Object, oOlInb As Object
    Dim oOlItm As Object, oOlAtch As Object    
    
    '~~> New File Name for the attachment
    Dim NewFileName As String
    NewFileName = AttachmentPath & Format(Date, "DD-MM-YYYY") & "-"
    
    '~~> Get Outlook instance
    Set oOlAp = GetObject(, "Outlook.application")
    Set oOlns = oOlAp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oOlInb = oOlns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    For Each oOlItm In oOlInb.Items
      
        '~~> Check if the email actually has an attachment
        If oOlItm.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then
            For Each oOlAtch In oOlItm.Attachments    
                 
                If Right(oOlAtch.Filename, 4) = "xlsb" Then
                    oOlAtch.SaveAsFile NewFileName & oOlAtch.Filename
                    MsgBox "SAVED"
                    Exit Sub
                End If

            Next
               
        Else
            
        End If
          
    Next
       
    ' DO SOMETHING
     
End Sub
```

For problem no. 2, I tried changing:

```
For Each oOlItm In oOlInb.Items
```

to:

```
For Each oOlItm In oOlInb.Items.Restrict("[Subject] = ""*DOCUMENT_APP*""")
```

It gives no error, it just exits sub.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/items-restrict-method-outlook "There is no way to perform a "contains" operation. For example, you cannot use Find or Restrict to search for items that have a particular word in the Subject field."

Comment: Jeee! That is bad news, so, is there a work around? look for only from specific sender? or look only attachement files that contains "DOCCUMENT_APP.xlsb" ??

Comment: The linked article describes alternatives.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do it with:
      strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%sketch%'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

niton gave a usefull link, I was able to get it done by using:

```
  strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%sketch%'"
```